# Conflict between Angular JS $scope and the MIME content-type of an API http response?

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, mime-types

I'm playing with an AngularJs app, consuming an API REST with Slim PHP through **$http** (next step: $resource, I know). It all works fine when retrieving data from the API when the controller's written like this:

```
angular
    .module("adminTaller", ['ngRoute'])
           ...
    .controller("CustomersListController", ['$http', function($http){
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.customers = [];
        $http.get('api/customers')
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                ctrl.customers = data;
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                ...
            });
    }]);
```

The 'customers' are displayed in this view:

```
<div ng-controller="CustomersListController as lstCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="searcher" />
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Apellido y Nombres</th>
        <th>Domicilio</th>
        <th>TE Celular</th>
        <th>TE Comercial</th>
        <th>TE Domicilio</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="customer in lstCtrl.customers | filter:searcher | orderBy: fullname">
    <tr>
        <td>{{ customer.fullname }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.address }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.cellphone }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.businessphone }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.homephone }}</td>
        <td><a href="#">Editar</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But in the moment I replace **this** by **$scope**:

```
angular
  .module("adminTaller", ['ngRoute'])
                ...
  .controller("CustomersListController", ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope){
            var ctrl = $scope;
            ctrl.customers = [];
            $http.get('api/customers')
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                    ctrl.customers = data;
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    ...
                });
        }])
```

, nothing seems to happen (I mean, no 'customer list' is loaded in the table), and Batarang gives me a weird warning (Chrome's console says nothing if Batarang is disabled):

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   application/x-js

My **api/index.php** sets the content-type to **application/json**:

```
$app = new Slim();

$app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');

$app->get('/customers', 'getCustomers');
$app->post('/customers', 'addCustomer');
$app->get('/customers/:id', 'getCustomer');
$app->put('/customers/:id', 'updateCustomer');
$app->delete('/customers/:id', 'deleteCustomer');

$app->run();
```

And in fact, the http request and http response headers look fine to me:

```
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/ng-taller/api/customers
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
**Request Headers**
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__ngDebug=true; PHPSESSID=b8cedd49edcc461fda62208e66cfb150; b8cedd49edcc461fda62208e66cfb150=DEFAULT%7C0%7C2M3TMlgUx3gTlaarYzHIdD28l8q9FTcNubt55%2BUGpAo%3D%7C7456bf61db3500c8bb7b3bc38082a470ce4a2ad3
Host:localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/ng-taller/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
**Response Headers**
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:1027
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Wed, 04 Mar 2015 00:26:12 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=97
Server:Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19
Set-Cookie:b8cedd49edcc461fda62208e66cfb150=DEFAULT%7C0%7C2M3TMlgUx3gTlaarYzHIdD28l8q9FTcNubt55%2BUGpAo%3D%7C7456bf61db3500c8bb7b3bc38082a470ce4a2ad3; path=/
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.19
```

When I inspect the view's scope/model with Batarang, it shows:

```
    { 
lstCtrl:  {  } 
customers: 
[  { 
id: 2
createdAt: 03-03-2015
fullname: Abelardini, Antonio Miguel
address: Virasoro Nº2533, Piso 3º - Rosario
cellphone: 341 (15)562-4484
businessphone: 341 430-4574
homephone: 
observations: 
logs: 
[  ]
errors: 0
 } ,  { 
id: 1
createdAt: 03-03-2015
fullname: Alvarez, Juan
address: Gallo Nº1254 (entre Nuria y Valdez) - Rosario
cellphone: 341 (15)485-6225
businessphone: 
homephone: 
observations: Puntual en el pago
logs: 
[  ]
errors: 0
 } ,  { 
id: 4
createdAt: 03-03-2015
fullname: Blanco de Escalada, María de las Mercedes
address: Av. Álvarez Thomas Nº1542, Piso 11º Depto.'A' - Rosario
cellphone: 341 (15)326-5484
businessphone: 
homephone: 
observations: 
logs: 
[  ]
errors: 0
 } ,  { 
id: 3
createdAt: 03-03-2015
fullname: Tirado López, Juan Manuel
address: Costanera Nº12 (Bajada de los Pescadores) - Rosario
cellphone: 341 (15)675-1125
businessphone: 
homephone: 3205 124-8586
observations: 
logs: 
[  ]
errors: 0
 }  ]
 }
```

Comment: If you want to use `$scope`, just use `$scope` (no need to assign it to `ctrl`). You'll also want to drop the `as lstCtrl` and just reference `customers` directly in the HTML. You should probably read up on when to use the *controller as* form and what the difference is to controller scope

Comment: Thank you, @Phil, I'll take into account! Do you have any suggestion where I could read on more about it? I'm certainly confused about it, and [Angular's controller documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) doesn't explain it.. and neither the sources I got! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with the mime type.

In your view, did you also change 'lstCtrl.customers' to just 'customers'? Otherwise you're pointing to a controller with nothing on it.

By the way, the way you had it the first time is the better approach. Using controllerAs syntax is preferred.

Comment: *"Using controllerAs syntax is preferred"* ~ got a reference for that?

Comment: Nope, I don't. I just work with angularJS every day in my day-job and follow along with new angular developments. ControllerAs is relatively new. It was added to make up for a few deficiencies in the old way of doing things (putting everything on the scope).
The simplest reason I can give is ControllerAs makes it possible to be explicit about which controller (or scope) you're targeting. If your element has an ng-model binding to 'fooCtrl.bar' you're less likely to reference 'bar' in the wrong scope. When you're working on a large team, data collisions are very possible.

Comment: "Otherwise you're pointing to a controller with nothing on it." That was the key of the problem of the non-displayed data, I guess... the mime-warning still exists but it wasn't related to the problem (and I can live with it by now)!